# Help with finding the probability of this exam question

Tags: probability, statistics

I need help with solving one of the questions the teacher gave us to prepare for an upcoming exam. I tried solving it but with no luck. Here is the question:

> On one shelf there are 5 hardcover books and 6 paperbacks and on the other shelf there are 7 hardcover and 4 paperback. From the first shelf we pick two books randomly and put them on a table and from the second shelf we pick one book randomly and also put it on the table. And at last we randomly pick one book from the table. What is the possibility for that book to be a hardcover?

**EDIT:** I gave it a shot with something like this: I calculated $P1$ like so with fractions $P(5 hard, 6 paper) = 5/11 + 4/10$ - so I can see the probability of taking 2 hardcover books from the first shelf then I gave $P2 7/11$ from the second shelf and the final P(A) I tried adding then together. This was of no use as you can see..

Comment: Can you show us some of the work that you've already done? That would really help us give a better, shorter answer faster because we could base it off of what you've already tried.

Comment: @NobleMushtak i gave it a shot with something like this: 

I calculated p1(5 hard, 6 paper) like so with fractions = 5/11 + 4/10 - so i can see the probability of taking 2 hardcover books from the first shelf then i gave p2 7/11 from the second shelf and the final p(A) i tried adding then together. This was of no use as you can see..

Comment: You should put what you've tried in your question by editing it and adding your work there. That way, it'll be easier to read because it'll be in your question and not in the comments. However, thank you for adding that! It might help us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the probability that, if we pick a book from the first shelf, it is a hardcover? Clearly, that is $\frac{5}{11}$.

What is the probability that, if we pick a book from the second shelf, it is a hardcover? Clearly, that is $\frac{7}{11}$.

Now, let's say that we pick a book from the table. It is either from the first shelf or the second shelf:

1. It's from the first shelf: The probability of this happening is $\frac 2 3$ and the probability of picking a hardcover from the first shelf is $\frac{5}{11}$. Multiply the two probabilities together to find that the probability of getting a hardcover from the first shelf by picking from the table is $\frac{10}{33}$.
2. It's from the second shelf: The probability of this happening is $\frac 1 3$ and the probability of picking a hardcover from the second shelf is $\frac{7}{11}$. Multiply the two probabilities together to find that the probability of getting a hardcover from the second shelf by picking from the table is $\frac{7}{33}$.

Now, we can add this two probabilities together to find that the probability of getting a hardcover from the table is $\frac{17}{33}$.

Whenever you have a problem like this, try to break it up into different cases. Then, multiply the probability that the case happens by the probability that the event happens in that case. Once you've done that, sum all of the cases up. These kinds of problems where you have to split probabilities up into cases is kind of problem, so this method of attacking the problem is very useful.

Comment: This is a solid answer but i have one question. We pick 2 books from the first shelf and 1 book from the second. Doesnt that change the probability of the first shelf so its not 5/11?

Comment: Yes, it does. As you can see, I multiplied $\frac{5}{11}$, the probability of picking a hardcover from the first shelf, by $\frac{2}{3}$, the probability that we pick a book from the first shelf, to get $\frac{10}{33}$.

Comment: Yes you are right sorry. Thank you i think i've found the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The other responder has given an elegant solution, but here is another way by enumerating it  a little bit.

Probability for any one case could be calculated such as this

P(Picking  a Head from the Table)*P(2 books being Head)*P(1 book being a head) for the first case.

The three books could be

H H , H  $$= 1.\dfrac{{5\choose2}}{{11\choose2}}.\frac{7}{11} = \frac{210}{1815}$$

H P,  H  $$= \frac{2}{3}\dfrac{{5\choose1}{6\choose1}}{{11\choose2}}.\frac{7}{11} = \frac{420}{1815}$$

P P,  H  $$=\frac{1}{3}\dfrac{{6\choose2}}{{11\choose2}}.\frac{7}{11} = \frac{105}{1815}$$

H H,  P $$ =\frac{2}{3}\dfrac{{5\choose2}}{{11\choose2}}.\frac{4}{11} =\frac{80}{1815}$$

H P,  P  $$=\frac{1}{3}\dfrac{{5\choose1}{6\choose1}}{{11\choose2}}.\frac{4}{11} = \frac{120}{1815}$$

P P,  P  =0\time{..} = 0

The required probability = $$\dfrac{210+420+105+80+120}{1815} = \boxed{\frac{17}{33}}$$

Comment: Yes thank you this helped a lot to me understanding the problem better as well. You've put it up very nice

Comment: You are welcome!!

Comment: @satishramanathan:  Good "natural" approach. More computation is required, but there compensating gains.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, Thanks for your compliment, Sir!!.

Answer (score 0):

Let $H$ denote the event that the book turns out to be a hardcover.

Let $S_{i}$ denote the event that the book comes from shelf $i$.

Then:

$$P\left(H\right)=P\left(H\mid S_{1}\right)P\left(S_{1}\right)+P\left(H\mid S_{2}\right)P\left(S_{2}\right)$$

Can you work this out?

---

Edit:

See the comment of @Noble to this answer.

It leads to:$$P(H)=\frac5{11}\frac23+\frac7{11}\frac13=\frac{17}{33}$$

In the answer of @Noble to your question you will find a nice explanation of this.

Comment: Im affraid i cant. How can P(H) have itself in its equation? I mean i can work it out if i take the numbers from @NobleMushtak answer but i need a way to get to those numbers first.

Comment: $P(H | S_1)$ means the probability that the book is a hardcover given that we picked from the first shelf, which we know is $\frac{5}{11}$ and $P(H | S_2)$ means the probability that the book is a hardcover given that we picked from the second shelf, which we know is $\frac{7}{11}$.

Comment: I saw your edit and its all clear now. Thank you for your reply i really apreciate it